# How do I reorder/clear the connection history in SQL Management Studio 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I connect to a lot of different servers in SQL Management Studio, but I find that not only is there no way to delete the old connections (dbnames, usernames, etc.), they also start to show up as duplicates.

Is there any way to clear them/reorder the history? I can't seem to find any easy way.

Thanks!

Comment: For SQL 2008, and Windows 7, you can delete/rename
C:\Documents and Settings\<USER>\Application Data\\(Local or Roaming)Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\SqlStudio.bin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue and found the file in question is SqlStudio.bin. I'm not sure how you'd go about editing it, but if you re/move it, you get a blank slate for your SQL connections.

We still use XP here at work, so the file is located in the C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell folder.

Comment: While this doesn't really let you tinker with the usernames, once you reset the file the passwords get memorized correctly. Thanks!

Comment: In Windows 7: C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `DialogSettings.xml` and `mru.dat` files in your `%AppData%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\ShellSEM` directory. I haven't tried tinkering with mine yet, but they look like they've got the relevant information in.

I suggest you back them up first though!

Comment: I think you can leave out "Roaming" in "%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft..." so it would be "%AppData%\Microsoft..."; At least in Vista.

Comment: Ironically, I didn't realise that "%AppData%" would actually work directly - it was meant to be a sort of "meta replacement" - for instance, my directory is c:\Users\Jon\AppData\Roaming. Thanks for the hint though - will edit.

Comment: Chris, are you still working on this? I've got a new netbook which I wouldn't mind install SQL Server Express 2008 (+studio) on, if you'd like me to investigate further.

Comment: Yes. I searched the registry and everything under SQL Server for a mention of my server's name and didn't find it, so now I'm thinking it's in profile now...but yes, if you find anything else that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to delete a connection you no longer need, select it in the Server Name dropdown and hit your `delete` key.  Not particularly intuitive, but it works.